# How do I automatically update a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I am a novice at php and mysql. Let's say my simplified fan fic site's mysql database has two tables one named `authors` and another named `articles`. Table `articles` has a column called `authorID` which is a foreign key which relates to column `authorID` which is a primary key in table `authors`. I have two forms on a html page each with php scripts that process them. one adds data to table `authors` (essentially a user registration form for authors that add data such as `name`, `email` and `password` to table `authors` to columns of the same names). The other form accepts an author email and author password and logs them in by comparing them to the values in table authors and if they match it creates session variables, one with `name` and another with `authorID` which if not set the user is not logged in. Once the user id logged in there's a third form which updates data to table `articles` (`title`, `subtiltle`, `article` to columns of the same names). When the user clicks `submit` in this form, the php script returns a success message as if my mysql query executed but nothing is added to table `articles` probably because my mysql query only adds values to columns `title`, `subtitle` and `article` leaving column `authorID` unupdated. So my question is how should I go about ensuring the system recognizes the logged in user by their `authorID` (primary key column from table `authors`) and update it to `authorID`(foreign key in table `articles`) whenever a user posts an article?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the author id with the form data when you are adding an article. You can include it as a hidden field in your HTML page with the value as your author id.
For example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="5">
```

When creating the SQL query, include the author_id field in the insert statement similar to title, subtitle, article etc.
If you have set author_id in the articles table as a foreign key, and an author with the sent id does not exist SQL will generate an Integrity Constraint Violation.

Since you haven't provided any code, I cannot answer precisely.

Comment: It worked. When logging in my user I set a session variable to the value of in the authorID column of table authors that mysqli_fetch_row() brings back when I search for a user during log in. What I did is assign this value that is stored as a session variable to another variable then sent that to the database along with the rest of the columns. Thank you, appreciate the answer